# Lua: Can I use a for loop to process all 'sometimes-nil' values in an array?

Tags: lua

I have the following code:

```
  local overrideNode = xml.first(rootFromOverrideXML,"nodes/node[@identifier='"..nodeIdentifier.."']")
  local overrideRefNode
  if (elementRef) then overrideRefNode = xml.first(rootFromOverrideXML,"nodes/node[@identifier='"..elementRef.."']") end
```

This results in `overrideNode` and `overrideRefNode` being nil in most cases. But either can be non-nil when something is found in the xml.

I have to handle `overrideRefNode` before `overrideNode`, so I wrote:

```
  for _,nodeVar in ipairs {overrideRefNode, overrideNode} do
    if (nodeVar) then
```

But it turns out that when both are non-nil, both are processed (two runs of the for loop, correct), but when `overrideRefNode` (the first) is nil, `overrideNode` (the second) is never processed (incorrect), so zero runs of the for loop, while it should be one run.

How do I loop over a set of two strings, either of which can be nil, but every non-nil must be processed?

Comment: Try `pairs()` instead of `ipairs()`

Comment: I think that still doesn't give you a reliable order, but I'm unsure.

Comment: No, it doesn't but you can grab everything and put it in an another table (which has no `nil`s anymore), and sort it whichever way you like.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is

```
  local overrides = {}
  overrides[1] = overrideRefNode
  overrides[2] = overrideNode
  for i = 1,2 do
    local nodeVar = overrides[i]
    -- Do some stuff here with nodeVar
  end
```